# <?xml-stylesheet?> if given before <?xml?> doesn't work in firefox

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb

i am generating an XML file using JAXB. First i write a `<?xml-stylesheet?>` instruction to FileOutputStream and then marhal my data to this FileOutputStream. i specify the name of file in FileOutputStream with .xml extension.

Now, my xml gets generated as desired and works fine in IE but fails in Firefox. Seems that Firefox expects `<?xml?>` as the first line where as in my case i've `<?xml-stylesheet?>` tag and then `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` tag.

i've to generated xml using JAXB and also add  info to it. Please tell how can i do it.

Comment: As per the XML spec, the xml-declaration (the `<?xml .... ?>` thingie) should precede all other content. If IE still works despite the order being wrong, then that's sheer luck for you.

Comment: plz tell me how to resolve the problem i am facing.

Comment: I don't see how this is JAXB-related. You're generating a file that firefox doesn't like, so find out why firefox doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `processingInstruction()` to add it in instead of spewing out your own.

Comment: can u plz tell me how should i generate my xml using jaxb and add xml-stylesheet tag as well?

Comment: Not a clue. Try calling `processingInstruction()` before any other functions.

Comment: @magic1234: Can u plz stp usng IRC style lingo here? Its rly hrd 2 rd.